# Spring Security Concurrency Control

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have used spring security 3.0.7 and I am implementing concurrency control in my project. But it is not working. I have used

```
<security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1"/>
</security:session-management>
```

Even I tried solution from [spring security reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#concurrent-sessions) but it didn't work out.
Here is my configuration file content :

```
  <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
   class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
  <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
  <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/session-expired.htm" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="myAuthFilter" class=
   "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
  <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
  <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas" class=
 "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
  <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
  <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

I am getting following exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Filter beans '<myAuthFilter>' and '<org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>' have the same 'order' value. When using custom filters, please make sure the positions do not conflict with default filters. Alternatively you can disable the default filters by removing the corresponding child elements from <http> and avoiding the use of <http auto-config='true'>.
Offending resource: class path resource [config/auth.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.checkFilterChainOrder(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:196)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.parse(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:86)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
```

Can anyone help with this question?

Comment: Can you define *not working*? I have `<sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />` alone and after logging in using second browser the first browser is logged out.

Comment: in my case when I log in using second browser it logs in, even I tested from third browser.

Comment: Indeed it will log in using second browser.  Does subsequent access from the first browser work?

Comment: Raghuram, how would it log in using second browser? it should give error because I've used 'error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"' attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have written `UserPrincipal` and `UserPrincipalImpl`(your own implementation), you should override Object's `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.

Comment: hi, could you enlighten us more of this solution? What if you have a custom authentication(implement `AuthenticationProvider`). Would this configuration suffice already:

`<security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1"/>
</security:session-management>`

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `concurrency-control` namespace element, a [ConcurrentSessionFilter will be added to the filter chain](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-concurrency-control) automatically, hence you cannot use `custom-filter` to add one at the same location or you will get this error.

The same problem will occur if you use `form-login` (or `auto-config`) and attempt to add a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` using `custom-filter`. It looks like that is causing the specific issue you have here (with your bean `myAuthFilter`).

You should probably add the rest of your `http` element configuration to the question to make it more obvious where the conflict is coming from.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says:

> Adds support for concurrent session control, allowing limits to be placed on the number of active sessions a user can have. A `ConcurrentSessionFilter` will be created, and a `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy` will be used with the `SessionManagementFilter`. If a form-login element has been declared, the strategy object will also be injected into the created authentication filter. An instance of `SessionRegistry` (a `SessionRegistryImpl` instance unless the user wishes to use a custom bean) will be created for use by the strategy.

So you can not use the custom-filter tag here. That is why it might be giving error. I took above content from this URL. Check this out:

Reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-concurrency-control

Answer (score 2):

add the following to web.xml:

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Comment: Yeah ! I have added but that is my own class which extends org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher

Answer (score 1):

I have the following applicationContext-security.xml and it works perfectly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.test"/>

    <security:http use-expressions="true">
        <security:http-basic/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1"/>
        </security:session-management>  
    </security:http>


    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="restuser" password="restuser" authorities="ROLE_RESTCLIENT"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

To test it properly you should do the following: open the websites in two different browsers and clear the cookies. The first time you can log in the 2nd time not. You should see the HTTP authentication form being displayed by the browser in both cases. If you dont see it means you are already authenticated in a previous session hence you need to delete your cookies. (to be on the safe side you should test it with two different browsers otherwise the cookies mith be shared)

Comment: Do you happen to have this source code anywhere? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: sorry, but this is about 9 years old, I don't have the source code anymore. The solution is  very likely outdated anyway. These days rather use java config instead of XML