# Spring Security session-management session-fixation-protection not working

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring 3.1 Security. Following is the part of my "spring-security.xml"

```
<session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
<concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/Login.html"/>
</session-management>
```

Though I set `session-fixation-protection="migrateSession"` still if I logged in using "Chrome Browser" then copy cookie value and open a "Firefox Browser" and go to the login page then edit the cookie and paste value from "Chrome Browser", then I see that I am logged in into my application. That means "session fixation attack" is possible !!!

Did I miss anything in my spring security config ?

It's just my following cofig file

```
<http auto-config="false" access-denied-page="/" disable-url-rewriting="true">

<intercept-url pattern="/test01*" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/test02*" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>

<form-login login-page="/Login.html"/>
<logout invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/"
        logout-url="/logout"/>


<session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">        
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/Login.html"/>
</session-management>

</http>

<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider>
<user-service>    
<user name="a" password="a" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
</user-service>
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Akash, Did you write UserPrincipal and UserPrincipalImpl classes?

Comment: nop i didn't write UserPrincipal and UserPrincipalImpl classes.

Comment: Post some portion of your code, so we can help you

Comment: As I said below, you should only have one `<session-management>` element, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 8):

If you copied the cookie *after* you logged in (as you've said), then that is not a session-fixation attack (at least not of the kind we protect against). The point is that the cookie changes when you log in, so that someone else cannot access your account. If you want to stop someone fixing a session which is already logged into their account, then that is a different matter and isn't something that can easily be protected against in this way.

Also, you shouldn't need to set this attribute as it is enabled by default. And just use one `<session-management>` element.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.I was checking out the book "Spring Security 3" by Peter Mularien. And in this book "Chapter 6" Page 173 he performed "Simulating a session fixation attack". I just did same as he did (What i explained in my post). But he is saying his one is working but my own project not working :(

Comment: Read it again - "Copy the session cookie value to the clipboard, then log in" ... He copies the cookie from Internet Explorer *before* logging in. You said you logged in then copied the cookie. Just check whether the session cookie changes when you log in.

Comment: :D Luke you are right. It's changing. Thanks a ton man. But is there any way to prevent this copy past cookie after login.

Comment: No. But it isn't a realistic attack. You shouldn't allow someone access to your browser's cookie list while you are logged in. And you should use HTTPS to protect the session cookie as it is transported over the network.

Answer (score 1):

It is beacause you supplied, `session-fixation-protection="migrateSession"`. That is session from Chrome browser is copied into Firefox browser's session. Also, it is logging in 2nd time at the same time which should not. This might be because, if you have provided your own `UserPrincipal` and `UserPrincipalImpl` classes, you have to override Object's `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods. Try it to make concurrency control working.

Also refer [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586824/spring-security-concurrency-control).

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I checked you thread where you had problem regarding concurrency-control of same time one user login. But thats not my problem. It works for me. My problem is with session-fixation-protection even if i set "newSession" still have the same problem. Can copy past cookie and it works in another browser :(

Comment: @Akash. no, that is not session fixation attack. Both sessions are different and new session is migrated to old one. You are logged in twice where you should be able to log in just once. So problem is in concurrency of sessions

Comment: please check my full spring-config file code. What else i need to do to prevent that. By the way i tried to login using same user account from different browser. And first one is gone away when second time logged. Then only the 2nd attempt is active. But when copy past cookie after login then can be same time same user in different browser :(